# Lists of Model Copies in a Model MVC 4 C# 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model

I have a list of model instances inside my main model.  How are these "sub-models" in the list stored?  My models in the list also contain a list.  Are these stored by base, reference, or value?

In essence, I capture my current model and store it to a list within the current model and allow users to re-fill the model with new data.  Because I capture the whole model I am also getting the list.   I have no issues with overflows, so I'm wondering how the models in the list are stored.

I have a model with a list of models with lists of models with lists of models....

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you attach a sample code that you have tried.

Comment: business code.  And I don't have time to mock it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your model:

```
public class Model
{
    public Model()
    {
        SubModels = new List<SubModel>();
    }

    public IList<SubModel> SubModels { get; set; }
}

public class SubModel
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

in razor view

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.SubModels.Count; i++)
    {
        <div id="tabs-@(i)">
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.SubModels[i].Id)
            <div>
                Name
            </div>
            <div>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.SubModels[i].Name)
            </div>
        </div>   
    }
```